# How to get the path to a file in a directory with multiple subdirectories

Tags: powershell

How can I programmatically get the path to the file if it is in a sub directory?

Example:

```
main_dir
     |
   sub_main_dir
         |    
       another_sub
            |
           File
```

I want to grab the directory to the file and invoke it, I know how to invoke the file with `Invoke-Item` but what I need is the directory that the file is in, in order to invoke it correctly:

```
function search_for_file($directory, $fileName){
  if (search_dir($directory) -contains $fileName){
    say("Package found. Invoking package, follow the steps in the setup wizard.")
    invoke $fileName
  } Else {
    say("Did not find package, check spelling and try again")
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Invoke-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\dev\testfiles MOCK_DATA_XCL.xlsx\' because 
it does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will search `$directory` and its subdirectories for the first `$fileName` it finds and then invoke it.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Recurse -Filter $fileName `
| Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName `
| Foreach-Object { Invoke-Item $_ }
```

**Response to comment**

If you just want to get the path to the file then you can simply remove the last pipe and assign the result to a variable:

```
$path = 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Recurse -Filter $fileName `
    | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: I would rather not invoke it in this function, I have another function that will be doing the invoking, all I will need is the full path to the file in order to invoke it from there. So basically I would need a way to save the full path to a variable and use it at a later time

Comment: `$FullPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Recurse -Filter $fileName | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName`